# Boost suddenly getting into my namespace, claiming errors for lack of functions

Tags: c++, oop, boost

In this new episode of the saga "Me vs Boost, libconfig, protocol buffers and glog", we find our protagonist (me) fighting against Boost in a desperate battle for the ownership of the namespace!.

Well, I've been using this pretty code:

server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H 1

#include "configuration.h"
#include "client.h"
#include "client_manager.h"
#include <string>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

namespace BBCP {
    namespace Server {

class Server : private boost::noncopyable {
public:
    Server(BBCP::App::Config const &wrapper) :
        acceptor(io_service),
        wrapper(wrapper)
        //signals(io_service),
        { }
    void run();
protected:
    void acceptHandler(boost::system::error_code const &error);
    void startAccept();
    void stopServer();
private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint;
    //boost::asio::signal_set signals;

    BBCP::Server::client_ptr newClient;
    BBCP::Server::ClientManager manager;

    boost::thread_group client_pool;
    BBCP::App::Config wrapper;
};

    }
}

#endif
```

for a few builds now, and it was working all good, until after... well, nothing at all, it started erroring:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/type_traits/has_nothrow_constructor.hpp:12:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/optional.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from ../include/server.h:10,
                 from main.cpp:17:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_constructor.hpp:36:1: error: ‘has_trivial_ctor_impl’ is not a member of ‘boost::detail’
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_constructor.hpp:36:1: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_constructor.hpp:25:8: note:   ‘BBCP::Server::boost::detail::has_trivial_ctor_impl’

(...) This goes on and on with a lot of dependencies.
```

Now, from what I can see, `BBCP::Server::boost::detail::has_trivial_ctor_impl` refers to some method defined in `boost::detail`. Point is, `boost::detail` shouldn't be getting into my namespace, `BBCP::Server`!.

To be honest, I can't see where this error came from, so...

Any help will be appreciated!,

Julian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a bug in one of the headers you included *before* which did not properly close the namespace.